# Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить в запрос sql "если то"

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить в запрос sql "если то"

Есть запрос выполняемый из php:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `_ba` 

SET `w_st`=`w_t`+`w_s`+`w_z`+`w_u`
```

В той же таблице есть поле w_rb со значениями: R1, R2 и R3

как задать условие:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `_ba`
```

если поле в таблице w_rb равно R1 или R2

то

```
SET `w_st`=`w_t`+`w_s`
```

если поле в таблице w_rb равно R3

то

```
SET `w_st`=`w_t`+`w_s`+`w_z`+`w_u`
```

Вот так не работает:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `_ba` 
WHERE `w_rb`= `R3`
SET `w_st`=`w_t`+`w_s`+`w_z`+`w_u`
```

Comment: Через select case.

Comment: `UPDATE _ba SET w_st = w_t + w_s + w_z + w_u WHERE w_rb = R3` Внимательнее надо читать руководства по sql. Сначала set clause, потом where clause

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию CASE:

```sql
UPDATE `_ba` 
SET `w_st` = `w_t` + 
             `w_s` +
             CASE WHEN `w_rb`= 'R3' 
                  THEN `w_z`+`w_u` 
                  ELSE 0 
             END
```

Обратите внимание на кавычки - они разные.

Comment: Теперь появилась ошибка:PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'R3' (T_STRING)

Comment: @АлексКраас Вы просили помощи с SQL-запросом. Ответ дан. Проблема кривого парсинга запроса в PHP - это совсем другой вопрос. А так, как написано в коде в тексте вопроса, с обратными кавычками - `\`R3\`` будет распознано как имя поля, а не как строковое значение для сравнения.